# How to represent the lag/settling time of a DC motor?

Tags: dc-motor, step-response

I have a 12V brushed DC motor and I need to calculate its lag/settling time or latency in other words. I did some experiments in which I gave motor DC supply of 5 volts recorded motor's steady-state speed using tachometer and then calculated the time it takes to reach steady-state using a stop-watch. Then I repeated the same experiment with following voltages: 1V, 2V, 7V, 10V, 11V, 12V. 
I have recorded the readings in a table with Voltage, steady-state speed and time taken to reach steady-speed.

As I am working on a project, I need to present about my findings of the response time of the motor. My question is that is there any better way, some kind of standard way,  to represent the settling time of a motor, instead of associating it with a different voltages as I have done?

Or, is the settling time associated with only with the supply voltage of the motor mentioned in motor ratings which is in this case 12V?

Comment: kV/RPM is the steady state coefficient. Rise time depends on current limit , magnetic impedance and thus motor power / weight ratio and has 2nd order inertia effects with RPM.  You can measure or estimate the weight , and inertia or use a 2nd order equation curve fit in excel.

Answer (score 1):

If you've not heard of Control Theory before, I encourage you to learn about it as it is a very good tool for describing things like this. Here, you're interested in finding the "step response of the system" (how the RPM changes with time after voltage goes from 0V to 12V). The RPM of your motor can most simply be modelled as a 1st order system (which is what you get if you translate Jansen's statement into differential equations). The step response of a 1st order system is an exponential equation with a start RMP, end RPM and a time constant (how fast the RPM changes).

Anyway, you don't have to care about any of this except measuring the RPM about 20 times per second (or more if your motor accelerates quickly) as it gets up to speed, then fitting an exponential curve to it and getting the time constant out of the fitted equation. You can repeat the experiment for different step sizes (0V -> 5V, 0->10V, etc) and I think the time constant is the same for all of them. You can then predict accurately the time it takes to make any change in RPM.

The setup for graphing the RPM can be done with an Arduino and tachometer, printing the results to serial. If you can't do that (but I think will get you much worse results) is to do it manually with a stop watch: first measure the steady state speed at a given voltage, then let it come to a stand still and measure the time it takes to reach 63% (the value reach at exactly 1 time constant, google "time constant" to learn why) of it final speed when supplied with a step input of the same voltage
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_constant#/media/File:Series_RC_capacitor_voltage.svg

At the end, if you're not happy with the response time, you could improve it by putting a control system around the motor, with a tachometer feeding into the control loop, turning the whole thing from 1st order to 2nd order system.

Answer (score 0):

Torque is proportional to current speed is proporitonal to the back-emf.

The back emf rises (as rthe speed rises) until the current allowed by the difference between back-emf and and the supply voltage exactly matches the drag caused by solid friction and aerodynamic drag.

Once you have the expression for drag at any speed, the current-torque relation, and the inertia of the motor you can predict how the motor will behave given any input voltage.